# Using IDisposable object in method that returns IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, resources

Imagine you have a method that internally uses an IDisposable object (for example a streamreader), and yield returns items as they are read from the file. Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<YourObject> Read(string filename)
{
    using(var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(filestream))
        {
            string line;

            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return new YourObject(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will the `reader` and the `filestream` be disposed when I use LINQ-methods that doesn't iterate the complete collection?

```
YourOjbect firstLine = Read("myfile.txt").First();
```

Comment: Have you tried checking that using debugger?

Comment: +1 Excellent question :)  I suspect we just have to trust the GC here.

Comment: It _looks_ like the filestream indeed is disposed. If I assign the filestream to a property and consult the filestream's properties after  the method is called, then most of them throw `ObjectDisposedExceptions`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use `yield` keyword compiler generates nested class, which implements `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator` and `IDisposable` and stores all context data:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <Read>d__0 : IEnumerable<YourObject>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<YourObject>, IEnumerator, IDisposable
{
    // Fields
    private int <>1__state;
    private YourObject <>2__current;
    public string <>3__filename;
    public Foo <>4__this;
    private int <>l__initialThreadId;
    public FileStream <filestream>5__1;
    public string <line>5__3;
    public StreamReader <reader>5__2;
    public string filename;

    // Methods
    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <Read>d__0(int <>1__state);
    private void <>m__Finally4();
    private void <>m__Finally5();
    private bool MoveNext();
    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator<YourObject> IEnumerable<YourObject>.GetEnumerator();
    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IEnumerator.Reset();
    void IDisposable.Dispose();

    // Properties
    YourObject IEnumerator<YourObject>.Current { [DebuggerHidden] get; }
    object IEnumerator.Current { [DebuggerHidden] get; }
}
```

As you can see, all local variables from context of the yielding method are moved to fields of this generated class. Interesting methods are those which have `m_Finally` in their names:

```
private void <>m__Finally4()
{
    this.<>1__state = -1;
    if (this.<filestream>5__1 != null)
    {
        this.<filestream>5__1.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, these methods dispose your disposable objects (`FileStream` and `StreamReader`). When the called? At the end of enumerating, or when `Dispose` is called:

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    bool CS$1$0000;
    try
    {
        int CS$4$0001 = this.<>1__state;
        if (CS$4$0001 != 0)
        {
            if (CS$4$0001 != 3)
            {
                goto Label_00AB;
            }
            goto Label_0074;
        }
        this.<>1__state = -1;
        this.<filestream>5__1 = new FileStream(this.filename, FileMode.Open);
        this.<>1__state = 1;
        this.<reader>5__2 = new StreamReader(this.<filestream>5__1);
        this.<>1__state = 2;
        while ((this.<line>5__3 = this.<reader>5__2.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            this.<>2__current = new YourObject(this.<line>5__3);
            this.<>1__state = 3;
            return true;
        Label_0074:
            this.<>1__state = 2;
        }
        this.<>m__Finally5();
        this.<>m__Finally4();
    Label_00AB:
        CS$1$0000 = false;
    }
    fault
    {
        this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
    }
    return CS$1$0000;
}

void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    switch (this.<>1__state)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            try
            {
                switch (this.<>1__state)
                {
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                try
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.<>m__Finally5();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this.<>m__Finally4();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

If you look to `First()` implementation of `Enumerable`, then you'll see - it calls `Dispose` after returning first item:

```
using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{
   if (enumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       return enumerator.Current;
   }
}
```

Thus `Dispose` of auto-generated class will be called, and all local variables, which require disposing will be disposed by calls to `m_Finally` methods.

BTW (not about usage with LINQ) if you look at [foreach statement implementation](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_15.8.4_The_foreach_statement) you'll see that enumerator is disposed after enumerating. Thus `Dispose` on generated class will be called even in case of `break` or exception.

Comment: Excellent! This also explains *why* they are disposed

Comment: @Thomas finding reason was interesting to me :) BTW one who dawnvoted can explain why he did that?

Answer (score 17):

Yes, they're disposed.

[Edit]
As long as you're using LINQ-methods or foreach loops, the disposal is taken care of automatically. However, if you decide to manually call `.Enumerator().MoveNext()` on the method, then you need to take care of the disposal yourself.
[/Edit]

This code:

```
class something : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing");
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace);
    }
}
static IEnumerable<string> ie()
{
    using (new something())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("first");
        yield return "first";
        Console.WriteLine("second");
        yield return "second";
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("before");
    ie().First();
    Console.WriteLine("after");
}
```

Prints:

```
before
first
Disposing
   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at TestApp.Program.something.Dispose() in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studi
o 2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Program.cs:line 198
   at TestApp.Program.<ie>d__0.<>m__Finally2() in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual
Studio 2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Program.cs:line 0
   at TestApp.Program.<ie>d__0.System.IDisposable.Dispose() in C:\Users\Tim\Docu
ments\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Program.cs:line 0
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studi
o 2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Program.cs:line 214
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args
)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySec
urity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, C
ontextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
after
```

Comment: It seems that the readers will be created and disposed each time the collection is partially or fully enumerated.

Comment: Well shouldn't that be the case since you say `First()` it no longer needs to read again rite ?

Comment: @usr The answer is right, because the question is not about the caller getting an enumerator, but the enumerator bieing created iwthin a LINQ execution, and then it IS disposed by the LINQ runtime when n longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general LINQ problem/question, and yes - LINQ will, when executed, dispose all disposable elements it gets.